# execute powershell commands with Lua

Tags: windows, powershell, lua, execute

I have a program that I work with, that has an onboard lua compiler to allow for custom written actions.

Since the tool itself is very limited, especially if it goes for complex reactions over networks, I want to use Powershell over lua.

Methods like `os.execute()` or `io.popen()` use the standard command line from windows and not Powershell.

Is there a way to use Powershell with lua?

---

I tried to write a command line script with the Powershell editor and run this script with os.execute, but it opens it as a textfile, it would be better to write the commands directly in lua but if there is no other way, executing a Powershell script directly would also be fine. (In Windows itself you can execute the script with right mouse "click/Execute with Powershell")

Comment: `os.execute[[powershell -file "c:\path\to\your\file.ps1" arg1 arg2]]`, script arguments are optional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```lua
-- You can generate PowerShell script at run-time
local script = [[
Write-Host "Hello, World!"
]]
-- Now create powershell process and feed your script to its stdin
local pipe = io.popen("powershell -command -", "w")
pipe:write(script)
pipe:close()
```

Comment: Works nicely without altering the execution policy

Comment: A very nice trick for small scripts; I'd hate to try to build and run a large script this way, though.

Comment: Any advice how to get output/response from PowerShell back to Lua? I am writing it to file. Bad way.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem makes it sound like you're using a command such as `os.execute("powershellscript.ps1")`, and that call invokes `cmd.exe` with your string as the proposed command line. Normally, Windows will open a `.PS1` file for editing; this was a deliberate decision for safety. Instead, try altering the `os.execute()` command to explicitly call PS: `os.execute("powershell.exe -file powershellscript.ps1")`. If you need to pass parameters to your script, enclose them in `{}`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help for more info on invoking PowerShell from the command line.

Comment: Nice but a problem, I get the response that running a script on windows is disabled. Now I can problably change that but since the tool, that is carrying that lua script, will work on many PCs at the same time, can I include an allowance within the script or can I somehow get around the allowance?

Comment: The MSDN link has the additional information you need to fix the secondary problem (can't execute scripts). What you're looking for is the "Execution Policy"; by default, execution of scripts is disabled in Powershell (again, for safety). What you want to do is override the default execution policy when you invoke the script - and that can also be done with a command line switch. Do read the material at the MSDN link.