# Elder Scrolls Online addon os/io or other filesystem access

Tags: lua, add-on

I wanted to try something out and work on a project where users would be moved in respective Discord/Teamspeak channels when close to each other in-game with the [ESO API](https://wiki.esoui.com).
For that I had something in mind to check for movement or region change of the player and then run an included powershell-script or a little .jar or .exe file or something like that. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41039879/6707985) for general lua and tried `os.execute` as well as `io.popen` with my commands and each time faced the error that `os` as well as `io` are `nil`.
This is my first time with lua so I was unsure if I was missing an import statement or something similar and tried `require "os"` that in-game presented me another error:

> function expected instead of nil

Which lets me assume that require will not work in the lua subset(?) of the ESO API.
Is there something I am missing or is there no option to have os-access based on in-game actions/events?

I do understand the potential of bad things one could do with this and I assume that this is the main reason why neither of the common ways is allowed to be used. Can this be confirmed?

And lastly I found [this bit](https://wiki.esoui.com/AddOn_Quick_Questions#How_do_I_save_settings_on_the_local_machine.3F) on the API's wiki page. My current plan (based on experiences before) would be to have a script or program monitoring the folder containing the saved variables, looking for new files, reading the variable values from them and delete them, so that they will be recreated on the next change of the in-game variable and trigger the script again. I assume that this is the closest I will get or are there other cleaner suggestions?

Comment: That error message does not come from the Lua core.

Comment: I am aware of that. However lua is the closest tag I could find and there is another question that had the same tags so I decided to use them as well

Comment: I wasn't complaining about tags, just trying to narrow where to debug.

Comment: I can paste the code if necessary :)

Comment: If os, io and require are nil, someone did not want you to leave the scripting environment they provide you. that's quite common. unless you happen to come by the ESO source code and build your own version you'll have to live with it I'm afraid

Comment: That was kind of what I was expecting :) Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community answer quoting comments:

> That error message does not come from the Lua core. [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222275/elder-scrolls-online-addon-os-io-or-other-filesystem-access?noredirect=1#comment77411162_45222275)

Which is correct and that means some restrictions are comming from the API itself.

> If os, io and require are nil, someone did not want you to leave the scripting environment they provide you. that's quite common. unless you happen to come by the ESO source code and build your own version you'll have to live with it I'm afraid. [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222275/elder-scrolls-online-addon-os-io-or-other-filesystem-access?noredirect=1#comment77412404_45222275)

Which did confirm my assumptions. So I guess the only way to have any connection to the filesystem is the way described in the question with the last link provided.

Edit: I found an entry in an official elderscrollsonline forum (which surprisingly I did not found before) [here](https://forums.elderscrollsonline.com/en/discussion/comment/3411654/) where the first comment as well states:

> I never tried but i'm guessing they were removed on purpose.

Just thought I put this here as well.