# Lua script read from serial port in OpenWRT

Tags: lua, serial-port, openwrt

I have Openwrt router with Arduino connected via USB FTDI adapter.
Serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0

Arduino code prints some data:

First part of data printed with delay via command `print()`, for example:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.print(var1);
delay(1000);
Serial.print(var2);
delay(1000);
Serial.print(var3);
delay(1000);
```

And second part printed with `println()` command:

```
Serial.println("");
Serial.println(var4);
Serial.println(var5);
Serial.println(var6);
```

So when I open Serial port in terminal I can see something like this:

```
1
```

then timeout in 1 sec, then

```
1 2
```

next timeout. and then

```
1 2 3
```

last timeout and

```
1 2 3
4
5
6
```

It works in Terminal program and in console in OpenWRT, for example `screen /dev/ttyUSB0`

I need make a Lua script that will read Serial port and print the data in the same way. I have a simple script, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
rserial=io.open("/dev/ttyUSB0","r")
while true do
chain = nil
  while chain==nil do
    chain=rserial:read();
    print(chain)
  end
end
```

it shows all data at once.
it doesn't show first 3 vars one by one with delays.
Seems it is because of rserial:read() - it will read until it receives a newline character.
It stated in similar question: 
[How to read from a serial port in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204242/how-to-read-from-a-serial-port-in-lua)

I tried to run this command as was advised there:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -icanon
```

but it doesn't help and I don't understand why.
Is it the way to fix this behavior via stty?
or I definitely need to use another Serial libs for Lua script?
All of these libs seems pretty outdated for now and I don't want to use outdated stuff..

Answer (score 0):

From the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.read):

> When called without formats, it uses a default format that reads the
>   next line (see below).

A new line is anything in the buffer until the next newline character.

So as long as you don't send a newline character Lua will wait one as it has been told by calling `read()`

Once a newline character is received you will be prompted any other character in that line.

Terminal programs usually update every byte to show what they receive in "real-time".

So if you want to have the same behaviour you may not use `read()` without any arguments.

Use `read(1)` to read every single byte without waiting for anything else.

Comment: I tried this also. when I use my Lua code and just change `rserial:read();` to `rserial:read(1);` it prints my Arduino output by one symbol in one row.
so if Arduino prints "Hello", Lua script prints:

    H
    e
    l
    l
    o

probably I need to check for newline character..

Comment: @TravErse of course it does. every `print` call starts a new line. use  `io.write` to avoid that.