# read and write on serial port with a lua script on raspberry

Tags: lua, serial-port

i'm currently working on a project aiming at controlling a RS232 device by a Raspberry pi4. I'm forced by other softwares to use a lua script and i never coded in lua, even if i have already made the code in Python... I've searched on google far and wide for an answer but have not found anything helping me.

I want my raspberry to open the COM port, and then read and send messages through that port.

I've tried [the lua user wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SerialCommunication) and [This post on stackoverflow (read and write on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603854/read-and-write-to-serial-port-with-lua-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) but both can't be applied to raspberry.

If anyone could help that'd be awesome !

here's my code in python if that can help you.

```
import serial

    def convertisseur(chemin):

        Tableau = []
        f = open(chemin)
        for row in f:
            Tableau.append(row)
        f.close            
        return (Tableau)


    def statut(ser):
        ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X07,0X01,0X01,0X41,0X60,0X00,0X73,0X45]));
        lecture=ser.readline()
        print(lecture);    

return()


    def main():
            ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
            ser.close()
            ser.open()
            Code=convertisseur('C:/Users/Ello/Desktop/CodePosition.txt')
            statut(ser) 
            ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X09,0X01,0X02,0X40,0X60,0X00,0X06,0X00,0X2C,0X45]));        
            ser.readline()
            
            ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X09,0X01,0X02,0X40,0X60,0X00,0X0F,0X00,0X25,0X45,0X53,0X08,0X01,0X02,0X60,0X60,0X00,0X01,0XF5,0X45]));
            ser.readline()
            statut(ser)

  
            print('Engine move in cm ? - for trigo, STOP to stop')
            Speed = input()
            while Speed != "STOP":
                speed = int(Speed)
                if speed > 38:
                    speed = 38
                if speed < -37:
                    speed = -37
            
                speed = round(abs((speed-38)))
                ser.write(bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in Code[speed-1].split(",")))
                ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X09,0X01,0X02,0X40,0X60,0X00,0X0F,0X00,0X25,0X45,0X53,0X09,0X01,0X02,0X40,0X60,0X00,0X7F,0X00,0X55,0X45]));
                ser.readline()
                statut(ser)
                Speed = input()
    
            print("Fin du programme, fermeture du port, passage du moteur sur OFF")
            ser.write(bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in Code[60].split(",")))
            statut(ser)
            ser.close()
            return   0
```

Comment: Could you add some information regarding the Raspberry OS, Linux?
Do you use Lua through the standalone interpreter or embedded in another program and if yes what is this program?

Comment: I'll use Ardupilot OS, and yes the script will be used as a part of Ardupilot programm, basically ardupilot send datas that are read by the script and used to action the RS232device. I'm pretty sure Ardupilot's OS is linux based. but without the hmi, thus i also use a standard raspi formatted card to code on the raspberry

Comment: When Lua is embedded in another program, you have to look into this program documentation. Somes standard Lua features could be disabled and some special features could be available.
I don't know Ardupilot but I would recommend you to look into the Ardupilot docs for serial I/O API.
It looks like the feature is available, see [serial_test.lua](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/AP_Scripting/examples/serial_test.lua) that seems to use [AP_SerialManager](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/AP_SerialManager/AP_SerialManager.cpp#L535).

Answer (score 0):

> I want my raspberry to open the COM port, and then read and send messages through that port.

Hi, try [vsergeev/lua-periphery: A Lua library for peripheral I/O (GPIO, LED, PWM, SPI, I2C, MMIO, Serial) in Linux](https://github.com/vsergeev/lua-periphery)
, especially [Serial section](https://github.com/vsergeev/lua-periphery#serial).

Not sure the dev path for you.
In my case the periphery COM device connect to TTL-USB converter, then USB of Pi, so path is '/dev/ttyUSBx'.
As I know, GPIO has UART serial support too.