# serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'com7'

Tags: python, flask, arduino, serial-communication

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response
import serial

main = Flask(__name__)

def serial_start():
    ser = serial.Serial('com7',9600)
    stop_flag = False
    while not stop_flag:
        if ser.readable():
            res = ser.readline()
            res_decode = res.decode()
            print(res_decode)

@main.route('/')
def hello_fnc():
    Response(serial_start())
    return 'Hello'

@main.route('/page', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def page_fnc():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return 'POST received'
    else:
        return render_template("index.htm")

main.run(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to use Flask and Serial-communication at the same time
but This app can't find port7 assigned to Arduino
a script related to Arduino works well without Flask

Comment: Are you sure that nothing else (the Arduino serial monitor, perhaps) has that port open already?

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, There is only a port assigned to Arduino on device manager

Comment: @박동주: This problem occurs when you don't specify the full path for the serial port. You need to specify the full path. For example, on a Linux it would be something like `/dev/com7`. I don't know what your system is, but hope this helps.

Comment: @SamMatzko now I'm using Window How do i get know full path for the serial port?
Does the full path  mean URL?

Comment: @Dongju: I did some research, and it doesn't look like the full path thing applies for Windows. In [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603854/read-and-write-to-serial-port-with-lua-on-windows?r=SearchResults&s=1|85.8212), they seem to be fine with just using "COM7", so that's not the problem. The only thing I can think of is that you aren't connecting to the right serial port. In the Arduino IDE, go to Tools/Port to see the avaiable serial ports, and try those.

Answer (score 0):

I had: serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': OSError(22, 'A device which does not exist was specified.', None, 433)

COM4 was show on my device manager. I booted several times, and still had problems with the serial port. I used PUTTY and I was able to use COM4, and see the output from the Arduino, but still got the error above.

I fixed my problem by opening the serial monitor, and then closing it.