# Lua uart connection serial port

Tags: linux, lua, serial-port, uart

I am trying to connect my sensor in uart to my device. I am supposed to send a couple of bytes, wait, and listen to the output. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way that works for me.

I tried to first send the bytes through io.open(locaation port) and then write into it, wait and then again read to obtain the response.

I wasn't sure I could use io.open to write, so I then used echo -ne byte > port. For listening, I still use io.read()

I have found library that enable a serial connection in Lua, but they make use of C libraries, something I cannot use.

How can I then write and listens to a serial port in Lua/linux with very basic commands.

Comment: So, what have you received with `p=io.open("serialDevice", "w+"); p:setvbuf("no"); p:write(string.char(byte,byte,....)); wait(); print(p:read(1):byte())` ?

Comment: What does the string.char(byte) do ? I basically used to do the following: p:write('0x10') for example.
I don't get any response back.

Comment: `string.char(0x10)` converts integer number `0x10` to string containing single character `"\x10"`

Comment: With `p:write('0x10')` you send string of 4 bytes: `hex 30,78,31,30`

Comment: Okay thank you. But still, it is not working unfortunately. There is response

Comment: How exactly "is not working"?  What problem do you have?

Comment: I am trying to do the following: send a request to the sensor, and then expect a response. The code runs but it cannot read a single byte back. So the code remains at p:read(1):byte(). 
I suspect that somehow the resquest didn't arrive to the sensor. Another option is that the sensor is broken, but the sensor worked in RVC mode (when I keep listening). But here I want to use uart to specifically ask a type of response.

Comment: Try `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 -icanon` command mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25213640/20468470)

Comment: Have you ever tried the write/read lua for UART protocol ? Because when I write everthing into a script it doesn't work, and I suspect the system assumes there are two processes in parallel, one for writing and the other for listening

Comment: Lua knows nothing about your serial device.  Lua treats it as a usual file-like object.  Lua can read and write by invoking standard OS functions for file operations.  It is OS device driver who is responsible for respecting the specific nature of the device.

Comment: Small update, now it is working fine. i assume there was a problem with the hardware.